# Problems encountered on running the app, crashes on run time and throws this error saying .dex file not found

Tags: java, dex, android-14

After updating my device from 13 to 14 while i run my app then app crash and throws this error     java.lang.SecurityException: Writable dex file '.../code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex' is not allowed.didn't find any solution anywhere.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Tried this but not working

File dexOutputDir = new File("path");
dexOutputDir.setReadOnly();

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.